# LINQ: Can I get a property from an object in a list, within a collection?

Tags: linq, drilldown

```
    foreach (ReportType t in reportsCollection)
    {
        List<Report> reps = (from r in t.reports where r.isChecked == true select r).ToList<Report>();
        foreach (Report r in reps)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(r.path));
    }
```

This statement works just fine. I'm just looking for a single LINQ statement that could maybe do this.

Basically, I have a report object with a property called isChecked. reportsCollection contains several reportTypes that contains lists of reports of that type. So the collection looks like this:

type1

- report
- report 2
- report 3

type 2

- report 4
- report 5
- report 6

and so on.

I want a LINQ statement that will grab all reports where `isChecked == true` within those types. I suspect a loop is necessary, but I was curious to see if the community had a solution. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to throw away that `.ToList()`, since that will make you loop through your list twice. First when doing `.ToList()`, and then again in the `foreach` loop. You should declare your collection as an `IEnumerable<Report>` instead, to keep it lazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use **SelectMany**

```
var query = reportsCollection.SelectMany(t => t.reports)
                             .Where(r => r.isChecked == true)
                             .ToList();
```

In query expression syntax form, you might write it as

```
var query = (from type in reportsCollection
            from report in type.reports 
            where report.isChecked == true
            select report).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice. I figured there was, I just don't know LINQ well enough to pull that off yet. Such a slick technology. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 2):

In query syntax it will look like this

```
var query = from t in reportCollection
            from r in t.reports 
            where r.isChecked == true
            select r;
```